# JQuery Autocompleter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am getting wrong suggestion while typing something in Jquery auto completer.
like if i type "ja" then it should show only those values which start from "ja' but its showing all.

and i would like to store values of this auto completer to some hidden field but i am not able to do it.below is my jSON format which is generated.so i want to show name as label and would like to assign value to some hidden field. 
`[{"id":1,"name":"Java"},{"id":2,"name":"Liferay"},{"id":3,"name":".Net"}`

below is my code snippet.

```
$("input#auto").autocomplete({
    source:function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<portlet:resourceURL />',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                featureClass: "P",
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                name_startsWith: request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.name, 
                        value: item.id, 
                    }                      
                }));
            },                                  
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    dataType: "json",           
    select: function (event, ui) {  
        $("#skillName").val(ui.item.value);           
    }
});
```

any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is the AJAX request coming back successfully?

Comment: Thanks for reply..yes i checked  response in firebug

Comment: If you are getting the wrong suggestions, that's a problem with the web service you're calling, not with the jQuery widget.

Answer (score 1):

The autocomplete code seems to be correct. It looks like it might be the webservice that isnt returning the results you are looking for.

Also, if you want the name to be displayed as the label, you should rename "name" to "label" because that is the key that jquery autocomplete uses by default to display the items in the dropdown.

For example:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Java"},{"id":2,"name":"Liferay"},{"id":3,"name":".Net"}
```

could be

```
{"id":1,"label":"Java"},{"id":2,"label":"Liferay"},{"id":3,"label":".Net"}
```

or

```
{"id":1,"name":"Java","label":"Java"},{"id":2,"name":"Liferay","label":"Liferay"},{"id":3,"name":".Net","label":".Net"}
```

The other thing that you could do is use a custom renderer to display the values inside name by doing something like this:

```
Input.autocomplete()..data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
       return $('<li></li>')
        .data('item.autocomplete', item)
        .append('<a class="ui-corner-all">' + item.name + '</a>')
        .appendTo(ul);
       }
```